# python where can I find JOBDIR variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

According to this question [How Scrapy filters the crawled urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621014/how-scrapy-filters-the-crawled-urls), there is a file called `requests.seen` in the directory defined by the **JOBDIR** variable

Please where can I find the JOBDIR variable ?

Comment: did you try `print JOBDIR`?

Comment: @MattDMo I got undefined variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [official tutorial(Jobs: pausing and resuming crawls)](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html) JOBDIR can be set from command line:

```
scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1
```

Comment: I run my spider, and Yes the file has been generated, but when I open it I didn't find the scraped URLs. Instead, I found lines like this `f6b696ffa8fbcd8fbd4eff777ba677091858a9c7` why please?

Comment: is that the finger print of a scraped URL please?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli in this directory scrapy will be storing all required data to keep the state of a single job (ie. a spider run), i.e. counters, offsets but not scraped lists of urls...

Comment: what i am looking for, is the scraped a list of urls, where can i find it please? i have a sence that this file contains it

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871613/scrapy-how-to-identify-already-scraped-urls or similar questions

Comment: How could I set the JOBDIR from a script?